Why does a Motherboard header to Dual USB panel mounted sockets include a capacitor?
I have a mini PC with a free 2×5 pin header on the motherboard that allows for 2 additional USB sockets.
I salvaged a suitable cable from an old HP desktop that leads to 2 sockets on a little pcb in a plastic housing, but when I opened it up I found that there is also a 470 µF 10 V capacitor connected to the board, between the 3 × Gnd and both +5V pins.
My question is, do I need to keep this capacitor? Space in the Mini PC case is a bit tight.
I haven't seen any mention of a capacitor included in the adapter cables available online.
Does anyone have an idea why this capacitor is there?
PS: I found another example, except this time the capacitor is 220 µF 10 V.

If something that could take a lot of current suddenly, for example a disk drive or coffee mug warmer, was connected, the reserve power available from the capacitor would be needed to avoid a voltage drop caused by the induction in the power feed from the PSU. If you disconnect the capacitor and the computer crashes when you connect or use a USB device, you know the capacitor is needed. I am not an electronics engineer.

There is also the issue of inductance in the cable on the power lines.  Sudden changes in current in the wire can cause voltage spikes due to the cable inductance.  Having a capacitor at the load end provides a charge reservoir limiting the rapid changes in current in the cable.  None of this fixes the same issue in the cable plugged into the USB port so I suspect the cap is not critical in most cases.  I have a vague recollection that the USB spec used to require a cap within a certain distance of the jack to be certified.

An interesting point about the USB specs - that lines up with this post that I found subsequently:
Accidentally knocked a capacitor off a laptop motherboard seemingly related to USB
I also noticed that, in both examples that I found, the capacitor is physically as close to the USB sockets as it's possible to get.
As I said, I couldn't find capacitors mentioned in the commercially available extension cables, but they are wrapped in a lot of plastic, so it's possible that there is also a capacitor buried in there.
I was going to write the capacitor off as a belt-and-braces thing, but now I think I'll try to keep it.


Does anyone have an idea why this capacitor is there?

USB specifications do require sizeable capacitors on every user-exposed USB downstream-faced (host) ports. The specs require to have 120uF on each port.
The reason for the capacitor is to prevent a voltage drop on an internal +5V voltage supply (which usually is the source for other USB ports and other internal ICs) when an external USB device is hot-plugged into the port. The issue is that every USB device/cable has input capacitance (limited to 10uF, but many devices, notably cheap USB hubs) can have much more. When hot-plugged, the USB device asserts a significant inrush current (several amps, depending on VBUS trace layout and use of ferrite beads), and the associated voltage drop can disrupt internal functionality of the host.
More importantly, the capacitor should be placed on each individual port, to de-couple this inevitable voltage drop from a neighboring port. The neighbor might already have some USB device running (hard drive or else), and you don't want to disrupt/corrupt its file transfer when trying to hot-plug another device (mouse, keyboard, or another USB drive) to your running system. This cross-coupling effect is called "voltage droop".
The voltage drop and droop parameters are subject of thorough tests during USB-IF certification process. It is advisable to purchase only USB-IF officially certified devices if you want to avoid functional glitches when operating your computer.

A few things to keep in mind:

Each wire can be regarded as a very long chain of RLCs in series.
due to that nature, adding capacitors to offset the inductance (Xl) of a
long cable.
Connecting a resistive load for example to charge something will draw lots
of inrush current and cause a voltage drop.
Noise on the power rail will be "eaten" by said capacitor.

